# How to complete a webhook form

Tags: webhooks, processmaker

I want to integrate one web site with a software (ProcessMaker).
The problem is that I have a survey in a web site that I want to pass the responses to my software using webhook. I have a client id and client secret from the software and also an endpoint but I do not know how to fill the webhook form in the website. The form is like below:

[image: click here to see the picture]

Where should I enter the client id and client secret?